# Crawl a wikipedia page in python and store it in a .csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

This is my python script code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon'
source_code=requests.get(url)
print(url)
plain_text=source_code.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
print("hello")
f = open('pokemons.csv', 'w')
for table2 in soup.findAll('table'):
        print("yash")
        for i in table2.findAll('tbody'):
            print("here")
            for link in i.findAll('tr'):                
                for x in link.findAll('td'):
                        for y in x.findAll('a'):
                                z=y.get('href')
                                print(z)
                                #f.write(link)
f.close()
```

All i want to do is crawl all the pokemons name from this wiki link
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon
but problem here is i am unable to get into the specified table i. e the table in which the all the pokemons names are stored but im my above code i m travelling through alll the table and trying to acces the "tbody" tag so that i will access "tr" tags in it but it not happening the same way !! tell me my mistake.

Comment: copy paste the table to excel or similar one, save it as csv

Answer (score 1):

The *tbody* is added by the browser so not in the actual source returned by requests so your code could never find anything using it.

All you need to do is get every *anchor* with a *title* attribute in each row:

```
with open('pokemons.csv', 'w') as f:
    table = soup.select_one("table.wikitable.sortable")
    for a in table.select("tr td a[title]"):
         f.write(a.text.encode("utf-8") + "\n")
```

That gives you 761 names, one per line.

If you were to use find_all and find, it would be like:

```
 # get all orws
 for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
    # see if there is an anchor inside with a title attribute
    a = tr.find("a", title=True)
    # if there is write the text
    if a:
        f.write(tr.find("a", title=True).text.encode("utf-8") + "\n")
```

Comment: but it is giving
f.write(a.text.encode("utf-8") + "\n")
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str

Comment: Then remove the encode, you are using python3, I was using python2

Comment: after removing it is giving
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2640' in position 7: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Open the file with, `encoding="utf-8"`.

Comment: do you mean open the file in encoding="utf-8" in python script or elsewhere? if elsewhere then what is its use cz python script will not run beforehand

Comment: In the open call, add the `encoding="utf-8"`